# Meteor.users is not ready when Meteor restarts

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

When developing, everytime I save a file Meteor restarts (which is an excelent feature), however some pages have some validatons based on the user profile and they are redirected to landing page. I was checking and it seems that Meteor.users is not ready yet. How can I sort it?

```
SpecialController = MainController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    const user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
    if (user && user.profile.internalStatus == "valid") {
      this.next();
    } else {
     // the routers is sending here but it shouldn't.
      Router.go('dashboard');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Meteor.userId is not instantly ready at restart and requires a short amount to be ready. The bad thing is that rendering often already happened then. The good thing is, that it is reactive so you can either listen in the template on it or use Tracker in combination with your router. If iron router supports before-rendered-hooks you could also use them to listen to user ID and only continue the  route when userId becomes present.

Comment: userId is OK, my problem is Meter.users, which is not ready. I was trying to use `waitOn` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the `Mereor.userId()` immediately, there is a subtle delay for it's readiness.

You can use `Tracker.autorun`to track the readiness of `Meteor.userId()`. `Tracker.autorun` allows a function to be called automatically whenever it's dependent reactive data source changes.

Simply speaking, `Tracker.autorun()` takes a function as input, runs this function and returns whenever the data source changes later on.

In your case, you can use `Tracker.autorun()` for tracking the `userId`, since `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` are reactive. In `componentDidMount()` call `Tracker.autorun()` and save the `userId` elsewhere when it changes.

Hope following code snippet helps:

```
componentDidMount() {
        var context = this;

        Tracker.autorun(function() {
            let userId = Meteor.userId();
            if (userId != undefined) {
                context.setState({ userId: userId });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Rahman's answer, you could simply write the code in `componentDidMount` like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   Tracker.autorun(() => {
      let userId = Meteor.userId();
      if (userId != undefined) {
         this.setState({ userId: userId });
      }
   });
}
```

Arrow function uses its container context as `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which takes an callback and execute it only when client is ready with all the data needed.

```
Meteor.runWithFullUser = function(cb) {
  Tracker.autorun((c) => {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    if(typeof user.profile !== 'undefined') {
      cb();
      c.stop();
    }
  });
}
```

Then use this

```
SpecialController = MainController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    Meteor.runWithFullUser(() => {
      const user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
      if (user && user.profile.internalStatus == "valid") {
        this.next();
      } else {
       // the routers is sending here but it shouldn't.
        Router.go('dashboard');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In order to make sure that you have `Meteor.userId()` when you run this method. You have to make sure to render the template only when the `Meteor.userId()` is present. To do that you can use top level layout template and do something like this

```
<template name="layout">
  ...
  {{#if currentUser}}
    ...
  {{else}}
    {{> appLayout}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Hope this will help.